# Vite: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, npm, vite

I know little about bundler and I'm using vite to build project, I got a error when import some package to configure dev server :

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

So here is the thing:

```
import pinyin from 'pinyin/esm/pinyin-web.js'

export const somePlugin = {
  name: 'someplugin',
  configureServer(server) {
    server.middlewares.use('/somepath', (req, res, next) => {
      const foo = pinyin('foo')
      next()
    })
  },
}
```

I don't use the normal way(`import pinyin from 'pinyin'`) , because that need a package `nodejieba` which need to install unnecessary `node-gyp`, so I choose the `web version` that don't need `nodejieba`.

I've searched the error,  some says add `"type": "module"` to  `package.json` file. but it already exist in my package.json.

however, I make the change:

```
// import pinyin from 'pinyin/esm/pinyin-web.js'
import pinyin from 'pinyin/lib/pinyin-web.js'
```

and problem get solved,I was confused because I thought vite prefer ES module.

So,
1> what cause the problem above?

2> why should I import file with extensions ? eg: `import pinyin from 'pinyin/lib/pinyin-web.js'`
I have to add extensions `.js` or it will cause error. while in `vite.config.ts` I needn't add extensions.

3> I tried to add field `optimizeDeps` in `vite.config.ts` like this

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), somePlugin],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['pinyin'],
  },
})
```

but it seems to be useless, the offical doc says:

"During development, Vite's dev serves all code as native ESM. Therefore, Vite must convert dependencies that are shipped as CommonJS or UMD into ESM first."

did that work for the frontend part and package "pinyin" is for the dev server so whether add the
field `optimizeDeps` there is no difference.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-glade-5qwe9n)